# How to generate an XML file in C# which is validated against a XSD schema file while generation?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

I have a schema definition file(.xsd) given by the government which will be used by them to validate the data sent by my client in xml file.

The data is retrieved from the database in a list in C# which is to be converted into a XML file.

The only solutions that i have found so far are:

1. Simply create the XML file from the list data first and then validate it against the schema file in your code.
2. Validate the data programmatically first by writing manual code using the validations in the schema definition file and then write it to xml file.

This way data can be validated either before or after the file is created. The first approach will impact the performance while if i use the second approach i will have to make the code changes if any of the validations in xsd file changes.

What i want is a way to validate the list data against the schema definition while the conversion to XML is taking place so that if there are any mistakes in the data, i will get an error or exception before the xml file is created and i don't have to manually write the code for the schema validations as the validations are already present in the xsd file.

Comment: xsd.exe (I think it's called) can generate classes for you that you can [de]serialize to/from. Is that a solution for you?

Comment: Are you saying that there is data in your database which might not validate against the schema? Then maybe you need to fix your database.

Comment: Yes i tried creating classes using xsd.exe. But when i serialized that class using XMLSerializer.Serialize() method, no validations took place. If i entered the wrong data into the object properties, the same wrong data was written to xml file.